# ERROR - [JSC_UNDEFINED_VARIABLE] variable previousPage is undeclared - Google Closure Compiler

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, compilation, google-closure-compiler, arrow-functions

I'm compiling 2 x JS files using Google Closure templates.  And for some reason, it simply does not like my arrow functions.  For example:

```
// let showCurrentPage;
showCurrentPage = (i) => {
    currentPage = i;
    paginationCountLogic(bookMarksArray);
}
```

If I change to a different function type, for example:

```
    let showCurrentPage = function(i) {
        currentPage = i;
        paginationCountLogic(bookMarksArray);
    }
```

My function becomes usable or recognised in my JS file.

> 'showCurrentPage' is declared but its value is never read.ts(6133)

My code works fine, without compilation. And I have been googling for hours, but I can not seem to fix this.

I have even tried changing my NPM command, to compile from ES6 to ES5.  But this does not seem to fixe the issue:

```
npx google-closure-compiler --js=app.js --js=pagination.js  --compilation_level ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS --language_in ECMASCRIPT6  --language_out ECMASCRIPT5 --js_output_file=minified.js
```

Any ideas?

Here's the actual error:

```
pagination.js:43: ERROR - [JSC_UNDEFINED_VARIABLE] variable showCurrentPage is undeclared
    showCurrentPage = (i) => {
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Where do you expect "showCurrentPage" to be declared?  In sloppy mode (not strict https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode), undeclared variable assignments are implicit but Closure Compiler requires you to declare variables (to avoid typos).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this answered via another question. But this turns out to be the reason why:

> The cause is probably that the compiler doesn't see the function being
>   called. Part of the advanced compilation is removing unused code and
>   renaming the methods/variables.
>
> Within your js or html it is never called because the function call is
>   only defined in a string value here :

```
for (var i = 0; i < individualPagesArray.length; i++) {
   document.getElementById("numbers").innerHTML += `<button onclick=showCurrentPage(${i+1})>` + individualPagesArray[i] + `</button>`;
}
```

you can solve this pretty simply by rewriting this:

```
window.showCurrentPage = (i) => {
```

to this:

```
window['showCurrentPage'] = (i) => {
```

See : https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/api-tutorial3#removal